# Running mysql 5.5 on centos 5.9

Tags: mysql, centos5

I installed mysql using `yum install mysql-server` on centos 5.9 and realized it's version 5.0. I need version 5.5 so then I did `yum install mysql55-server` however I couldn't find a way to start server version 5.5 instead of 5.0.

`service mysqld start` will start 5.0 server and removing mysql 5.0 doesn't help either because `service mysqld start` fail to find mysqld service

**Update 1 Nov 2013:**

I noticed mysql55 package was being installed to `/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin`, so I appended that into the start of my PATH env var but `service mysqld start` still runs 5.0 server.

If I tried running the server using `mysqld_safe` located on above mysql55 path but it says

```
[root@***** bin]# mysqld_safe
Use "scl enable mysql55 'service ...'" invocation
```

Not quite sure what it means.

I checked the running mysql version by connecting to it using mysql command line client.

```
[root@***** bin]# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.0.95 Source distribution
```

Comment: Check the log files and post their output. Logs should be in `/var/log/mysql` or similar location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be running a [Red Hat Software Collection](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/09/12/rhscl1-ga/). These are specially built software packages which exist outside the standard system and thus require special commands to use.

For instance, the updated package's init script will be prefixed with the software collection's name:

```
service mysql55-mysqld status
```

And you must start a command with `scl enable` if you want the command to have access to the software collection.

```
scl enable mysql55 mysql -u root -p
```

See the [release notes](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html/1.0_Release_Notes/index.html) for more, including instructions on upgrading a MySQL database from 5.x to 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I actually found the solution. Once mysql55 package is installed, when I list available services using `service --status-all | grep mysql` there's another service called mysql55-mysqld. To start/stop mysql55 I need to use

```
service mysql55-mysqld start
service mysql55-mysqld stop
```